# How to Round numbers in database to two decimal places using a MySql query

Tags: mysql, decimal, rounding

I want to round the numbers to 2 decimal points in a woo commerce database table `wp_postmeta`.
There is a column `'meta_key'` with row `'_price'` and a column `'meta_value'` which has all kinds of data in it as well as the numbers in the row `'_price'` that need to be rounded and reduced to two decimal places.
(I know I'll also have to do that for `_regular_price`)

I am a complete beginner with SQL. I've managed to do a few things in PHPMyAdmin by using the Search to give me the syntax or copying and changing answers found on the net, but this one has me stumped, just not enough knowledge yet.

I managed to add 10% to all the prices with this query -

```
update wp_postmeta set meta_value = meta_value * 1.10 where meta_key='_regular_price'
```

I've read that there's a 'ROUND' function, but not sure how to write the query.

I'm guessing it would be something like this -

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta ROUND meta_value where meta_key='_price'
```

Hope someone here can help.

Comment: Look again at the format of your successful UPDATE. Also, when using an EAV, it's still a really good idea (if possible) to store values in columns of suitable data type.

Comment: "all kinds of data in it as well as the numbers" - Does it mean that you have all the information stuffed into a `VARCHAR` column?

Comment: The meta_value column consists of all kinds of data, only the meta_value for meta_key '_price' and _regular_price' are the fields I want to round to 2 decimal places, the other data isn't dollar values .

Comment: The column should be *defined* with two decimal places, e.g. DECIMAL(8,2).

Comment: I just have to ask - 'woo' commerce? Typo, Web Of Objects, spiritual 'woo' community...?

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation on `round`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) says:

> `ROUND(X)`, `ROUND(X,D)`
>
> Rounds the argument X to D decimal places. [...] D defaults to 0 if not specified.

So your [`update`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) would be:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET    meta_value = ROUND(meta_value, 2)
WHERE  meta_key='_price'
```

#### Display formats

If your concern is to *display* a number with 2 decimal digits, it might be better to keep the complete precision as it is, but change the way you `select` values from your table, and us [`format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format):

Without the above update, you can still do this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(meta_value, 2)
FROM   wp_postmeta
WHERE  meta_key='_price'
```

If in your table you have the value 15.002916 then the above `select` will render it to a string: `15.00`.

Finally, if the data type of `meta_value` is a `varchar` (so, not a numerical data type), you can of course store the additional trailing zeroes:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET    meta_value = FORMAT(meta_value, 2)
WHERE  meta_key='_price'
```

But do realise that this only works as expected if the data type is of the text kind. In numerical data types the values 15.00 and 15 are *exactly* the same; it is just their display format which is different.

Comment: Thanks very much trincot, exactly what I wanted. It did remove any trailing zero's- so 15.0045707 resulted in 15 rather than 15.00, but Woocommerce adds the zero's back in automatically.

Comment: You're welcome. I have updated my answer with information about how you can deal with trailing zeroes in the database itself. But yes, if Woocommerce does the job for you, it is of course a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can round your column with Round Function ,
Use function like this :

```
SELECT ROUND(column_name,decimals) FROM table_name;
```

in this case write query like below :

```
select Round(_Price , 2) from your table name
```